# Find min/max of separate columns after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe that I want to groupby

```
TO    FROM    sort    toName    fromName    toLoc    fromLoc      max    min    
 A      B      0       test       test       test      test        10     8
 A      B      0       test       test       test      test        9      2
```

The idea is to groupby the `sort` column but preserve the max/min values. The highest `max` value and the lowest `min` values are the ones I want to populate.

```
TO    FROM    sort    toName    fromName    toLoc    fromLoc      max    min    
 A      B      0       test       test       test      test        10     2
```

I can't figure out how to do the comparison **and** groupby at the same time, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First do the groupby, and then using [aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html), you can get the min and max of two columns:

```
import numpy as np

agg_dict = {"min": np.min, "max": np.max}
# OR YOU CAN DEFINE IT AS 
agg_dict = {"min": "min", "max": "max"}
df = df.groupby("sort").aggregate(agg_dict)
```